# Error ENOENT on child process when executing command in javascript

Tags: node.js, spawn, aws-vault

I want to execute `aws-vault` with 2 arguments as a script in my `package.json`. Therfore I created a little helper script:

`deploy.js`

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const args = process.argv.slice(2);

const child = spawn(
  `aws-vault exec ${args[0]} -- sls deploy --stage ${args[1]}`,
);

child.on('close', code => {
  console.log(`aws-vault process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

and in my `package.json` the script is defined like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "serverless offline --httpPort=4000",
    "deploy": "node deploy.js $@"}
```

but when I run `yarn deploy myprofile mystage`

I receive the following error:

```
 errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn aws-vault exec myprofile -- sls deploy --stage mystage',
  path: 'aws-vault exec myprofile -- sls deploy --stage mystage',
  spawnargs: []
```

I am not sure what I missed... the command looks correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the `{ shell: true }` and try again.

```js
const child = spawn(
  `aws-vault exec ${args[0]} -- sls deploy --stage ${args[1]}`,
  [],
  { shell: true }
);
```